# a question about relationship between characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

The matrix is
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1\\
1 &  0
\end{pmatrix}$$
I found out that the characteristic polynomial is $x\times x+1$, so for the possible conditions of minimal polynomial, are they $x$ and $x\times x$? I have tried both but none of them equals $0$.

Comment: Hint: The minimal polynomial must divide the characteristic polynomial.  What divides $x^2 + 1$?

Comment: i think one is the only answer

Answer (score 2):

We know that the minimal polynomial divides all other polynomials such that $p(A)=0$ where $A$ is your matrix. So, if we say that $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial and $c(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial, we have $p(x) \mid c(x)$ but since $c(x)=x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{R}$ we get $p(x)=x^2+1$. So, the minimal polynomial is the same as the characteristic polynomial in this particular case.

**Addendum:**

If we work over $\mathbb{C}$ then $x^2+1 = (x-i)(x+i)$, so it isn't irreducible any longer but $A+iI \neq 0$ and $A-iI \neq 0$, so even if we work over $\mathbb{C}$ we still have $p(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: I add that $x^2+1$ is not irreducible on $\mathbb{C}$, but also in that case it is the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @enzotib: Yes, good point. I added your point to my post.